# Selenium Assertion for Negative Scenario Java

Tags: java, selenium, testng, testng-dataprovider

I'm trying to assert a negative test case for gmail login in selenium but ending up with getting an exception. Could anyone suggest what's the issue?

```
 @Test(dataProvider="LoginData")
public void testMethod(String email,String password) throws InterruptedException{
            browser.findElement(By.id("Email")).clear();
            browser.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys(email);
            browser.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys(password);
            browser.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
            browser.wait(30000);
            assertTrue(browser.getPageSource().contains("The username or password you entered is incorrect."));
```

}

Generated exception

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at seleniumExcel.DataProviderAutomation.testMethod(DataProviderAutomation.java:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not feasible to grab whole page source to test only one small error text. The best way will be to find the element(of course you want me make sure first if the element exist) and perform `.contains()` on that. Since, you did not provide any `html` I am not sure how you can you find the target element. But definitely you want to use `FindElement()`. Something like the following is the code block you may want

```
@Test(dataProvider="LoginData")
public void testMethod(String email,String password) throws InterruptedException{
    WebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver();
    browser.findElement(By.id("Email")).clear();
    browser.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys(email);
    browser.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys(password);
    browser.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
    browser.wait(30000);

    try{
        String error = browser.findElement(By.id("Your id")).getText();
        assertTrue(error.contains("The username or password you entered is incorrect."));

       }catch (NoSuchElementException e){
         //something else
       }
}
```